# Installation of Pyephem via pip Fail

Tags: pyephem

Recently, I try to install Pyephem in my vitual environment of Ubuntu by using command `$ pip install pyephem`.

However, it fails to create local `bin` file. The error is "Permission Denied". I wonder how can I solve this problem. Your help will be kindly appreciated.

Comment: Could you paste in the full output of pip? That can be helping in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: @BrandonRhodes thank you for replying me. The errors i found in the output are: (libastro-3.7.6/satspec.h:16:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes] ) & (libastro-3.7.6/plmoon.c:126:2: warning: case value ‘11’ not in enumerated type ‘PLCode’ [-Wswitch]) . The second one is continued until case value '28'. Then (error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ephem': Permission denied ) is shown. Does this information is enough?

Comment: @BrandonRhodes i tried again by typing $ sudo pip install phephem and it worked. I wonder what is the difference between having sudo and without having sudo. Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install PyEphem into the system directories on your machine, instead of under your home directory, but only the system administrator is allowed to write to the system directories like `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`.

By adding `sudo` in front of the command, you run it with the high permissions of the administrator instead of with your usual limited user-level permissions, which is why it is able to succeed and write files to the system directories on your machine.

If you are interested in installing PyEphem only under your user account without needing special permissions, try reading about the [Virtualenv tool](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).